# How to set `screen` environment variable from bash?

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-screen

### Background

I use `virtualenv` to switch between environments "1.0" and "2.0".
I use `screen` to manage terminals.
When I work on one environment I want all new `screen` windows to start with this environment.

### Question

Can bash instruct `screen` to set environment variable on new shell instances, so I could make an alias similar to this one:

```
alias one='export PRJCT=1.0; screen-magic-setenv PRJCT=1.0; workon 1.0'
alias two='export PRJCT=2.0; screen-magic-setenv PRJCT=2.0; workon 2.0'
```

and afterwards in `~/.bashrc` call:

```
[[ -z $PRJCT ]] || workon $PRJCT # switch to project if set
```

I know I can command `screen` to set environment variable on new shells like below but it doesn't help as it won't work in an alias:

```
:setenv PRJCT
2.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is you cannot find a way to use a shell alias to interact with screen directly. Instead, you can send commands to a running screen using `-X`, including `setenv` of course, e.g.:

```
$ screen -list
There are screens on:
    25216.pts-45.antiriad      (Attached)

$ screen -S 25216 -X setenv PRJCT 2.0
```

The variable is then set, and will be inherited by child shells from that point on, exactly as with `:setenv`.
If you use `-S` to set sensible distinct session names your task may be easier. The variable `STY` holds the current screen session.

If you run just `screen -X setenv PRJCT 2.0`  within a screen session, omitting `-S`, it will apply to that screen instance.

```
alias one='export PRJCT=1.0; screen -X setenv PRJCT 1.0; workon 1.0'
```

Comment: Only tested it now and as expected, worked like a charm. Thanks mate.

Comment: Isn't there a permanent way to always have the environment variables when a new screen is created?

Comment: @AndréYuhai - You can use `setenv` in the configuration to do this. Instead though, I use a test like `if [ "$TERM"  = "screen" ]` in my `.bashrc` as it's is more flexible.