# Set multiple environment variables for existing screen session

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-screen

I have an existing screen session and now I need to set some (more than one) environment variables to that session. These environment variables should not be visible to other screen sessions. I tried the solution in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157202/how-to-set-screen-environment-variable-from-bash) which didn't work.

I tried

```
screen -r "myscreen" -X setenv x x_value;y y_value;z z_value
```

Here I got an error

```
-bash: x: command not found
-bash: y: command not found
```

then I tried

```
screen -r "myscreen" -X setenv x x_value;setenv y y_value;setenv z z_value
```

which gave me

```
-bash: setenv: command not found
-bash: setenv: command not found
```

How can I set multiple variables at once?

Comment: Why don't you just run `var=value` in the running screen session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the `setenv` command,  try the `export` command

```
export myEnvVar="echo \"It works!\""
```

`bash $~/ $myEnvVar`

Output:
`It works!`

---

To make it permanent for your user:
in the .bashrc file (usually your your /home//folder)
add it at the last line, and reload the bash shell.

I.e you could add the following lines:

```
export myEnvVar="echo \"It works\""
echo $myEnvVar
$myEnvVar
```

---

And to reload the bash shell - reopen it(the terminal) or just type bash.